# React DatePicker show month & year dropdown for all months with multiple months shown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, react-datepicker

I'm trying to use the DatePicker from react-datepicker in my web app. I'd like there to be 2 months shown in the DatePicker, with the month and year dropdown shown for both months.

Tried playing around in the documentation site. However I'm unable to get the desired effect. Basically would like the dropdown month & year pickers (shown in the red box in the image below) to be visible for the month on the right as well.

View Image:
[Image of the date-picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXcep.png)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
  const onChange = (dates) => {
    const [start, end] = dates;
    setStartDate(start);
    setEndDate(end);
  };

  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={onChange}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      selectsRange
      monthsShown={2}
      showMonthDropdown
      showYearDropdown
      dropdownMode="select"
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: So, what you exactly want?

Comment: Here is the image of the component: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXcep.png . Basically want the dropdown menu to be available for the 2nd month also, not just the 1st like it is in the image.

Comment: you can't because, in the second column picker shows next month. If you really want this, you need second datePicker.